# Uploading files in django admin, download through public site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am running a Django website and I want to be able to upload a file through my admin panel and then have visitors to the main site be able to download it.  I am running my site using Django-nonrel, Django FileTransfers and Google App Engine.  I believe the upload functionality is working correctly as I am able to see the file in my App Engine Blob Storage.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to present a download link to the specified file on the public website.  I have pasted the relevant classes below:

---

I have an app called Calendar, that has the following model:

```
class CalendarEvent (models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField()

    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/')
```

Here is the view:

```
def calendar(request):
events = CalendarEvent.objects.exclude(start__lt=datetime.datetime.now()).order_by('start')
return render_to_response('home/calendar.html',{'events': events},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def download_handler(request, pk):
    upload = get_object_or_404(CalendarEvent, pk=pk)
    return serve_file(request, upload.file, save_as=True)
```

Here is my admin:

```
class calendarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','start','end')

admin.site.register(CalendarEvent, calendarAdmin)
```

Finally, here is the relevant part of my template:

```
    {% for e in events %}
    {% url Calendar.views.download_handler pk=e.pk as fallback_url %}
    <a href="{% firstof e.file|public_download_url fallback_url %}">Download</a>
{% endfor %}
```

{% firstof e.file|public_download_url fallback_url %} is just returning blank, i'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The GAE blob store does not support public download according to the documentation [here](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers), so if you use the default backend for public download urls, it returns None. So my guess is that `e.file|public_download_url` always return None. You could verify that.

Then I think your template is wrong. You're trying to access `e.views.download_handler` where it should be `Calendar.views.download_handler` if your app is named Calendar.

I think the sample on the django-filetransfers page is error prone because the variable used in the template loop has the same name as the sample app: "upload".

If this doesn't fix it, could you post your *urls.py* from Calendar app. It could be that the template's `url` method is not able to resolve the url for `Calendar.views.download_handler` if there is no mapping in `urlpatterns`.

You should have something like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('Calendar.views',
    ...
    (r'^download/(?P<pk>.+)$', 'download_handler'),
    ...
)
```

in this file.

Comment: I think the missing urlpatterns declaration did it!

Comment: That would explain the blank url in your template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything special, eg

```
<a href="{{ e.file.get_absolute_url }}">Download File</a>
```

should work, or just use `e.file.url` directly?

Comment: this isn't working {{ e.file.get_absolute_url }} was just resolving to the current pages location (i.e. mywebsite.com/calendar.html)

Comment: @zpesk I think you mean it evaluated to an empty string, making the attribute `href=""`, which is a relative URL that points to the current page. This makes sense as I don't believe `FieldFile` provides `get_absolute_url`. But what about `e.file.url`?

Comment: @JameySharp e.file.url is giving me an error: "Caught AssertionError while rendering: The service "images" doesn't have a CreateRPC method." - it's not a terribly descriptive error some i'm not sure how to debug it - I know the file is being successfully uploaded because I can see it in the App Engine Blob Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't deployed on Google App Engine myself, but this appears to be what django-filetransfers was designed for:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers#handling-downloads

---

edit: I believe I've answered this in the other question you posted, then: [Trouble downlaoding file using Django FileTransfers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187401/trouble-downlaoding-file-using-django-filetransfers)

Comment: I'm actually using that, but can't seem to figure out what is going wrong - see the edits I just made to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way is to write a view since this file blob cannot be retrieved directly to write a function which is such:

```
def file_transfer(req, calendar_event_id):
    try:
       ce = CalendarEvent.objects.get(calendar_event_id)
    except CalendarEvent.DoesNotExist:
       raise Http404()

    file = ce.file (Write Google appengine specfic routine to pull file)
    return HttpResponse(file, media_type='file content type')
```

Hook it up on urls.py