# Trouble downloading file using Django FileTransfers

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, download

I have am uploading a file through the admin section of my site that I would like to be able to be publicly downloaded through my website.  I know that the file I have uploaded has been successfully uploaded because I can view it in the App Engine Blob storage.  I am having trouble finding out what isn't working with the code below:

relevant part of my modeL:

```
class CalendarEvent (models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/')
```

in my views.py file the relevant code is:

```
def calendar(request):
    events = CalendarEvent.objects.exclude(start__lt=datetime.datetime.now()).order_by('start')
    return render_to_response('home/calendar.html',{'events': events},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def download_handler(request, pk):
    upload = get_object_or_404(CalendarEvent, pk=pk)
    return serve_file(request, upload.file, save_as=True)
```

in my template the relevant code is:

```
{% for e in events %}
    {% url Calendar.views.download_handler pk=e.pk as fallback_url %}
    <a href="{% firstof e.file|public_download_url fallback_url %}">Download</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What symptoms have you observed?

Comment: @JameySharp {% firstof e.file|public_download_url fallback_url %} resolves to nothing so my Download link is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your view name for your download_handler should be `<appname>.views.download_handler`. You probably don't have an app named "e" with an appropriate view in it.

Comment: I changed it to  {% url Calendar.views.download_handler pk=e.pk as fallback_url %}, but it still isn't working :(

Comment: @zpesk, module names are typically all lowercase. If you wanted to import the `download_handler` function in your Python source, what module name would you import it from? Then use that name.

Comment: the app name is "Calendar" - I'm not sure what else would be put there? Any suggestions?

Comment: @zpesk, try running "`python manage.py shell`", then "`from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`", then "`reverse('Calendar.views.download_handler')`". If that returns the right URL path, then indeed, that part of your template is correct. Otherwise, the exception it throws should help you (and us) figure out what's wrong.